# Magmi Import - Error Messages

Tags: magento-1.9, import, mysql, magmi

I'm trying to import products from a CSV file and keep getting errors.  The following 2 errors appear for each row in the CSV file.  Seems (at least to me) that it could be a category issue?!?!  Can someone please help me diagnose and fix the issue?  Thank you in advance!

```
error 1:SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'dbname.cce.entity_type_id' isn't in GROUP BY - SELECT cce.entity_type_id,cce.attribute_set_id,cce.level+1 as level,COALESCE(MAX(eac.position),0)+1 as position

FROM catalog_category_entity as cce

LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity as eac ON eac.parent_id=cce.entity_id

WHERE cce.entity_id=?

GROUP BY eac.parent_id
error 2:SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'dbname.cce.entity_type_id' isn't in GROUP BY - ERROR ON RECORD #1
```

Comment: can you give us a sample of your CSV file which is causing the issue

Comment: Make sure you update and protect Magmi, [it probably was used to infect about 8000 websites](http://www.securityweek.com/thousands-magento-sites-abused-malware-distribution) this weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a slight difference in the versions of PHP (5.6 and 5.7) that can cause this.  There is a known issue on GitHub where the Magmi project is hosted.

In your Magmi directory, navigate to the following file: `magmi/plugins/extra/itemprocessors/categories/categoryimport.php` and make the following change.

```
GROUP BY eac.parent_id";
```

to

```
GROUP BY eac.parent_id,cce.entity_type_id,cce.attribute_set_id,level";
```

Source: https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git/pull/216/files

Answer (score 1):

I just found the issue.

Easy fix... locate your MySQL config file, mine was `etc/my.cnf`.  Remove: **ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY**.  This is what's returning the errors.